# How to predefine and hide a column in SharePoint NewForm and EditForm?

Tags: sharepoint, hidden

does anyone know how to predefine a column and hide it in SharePoint? I want to create a second NewForm for an already existing List. A new column with two options will make sure to differentiate the two entries in reports/views.

Example:

I have a list with two columns: Name (text) and Type (choice). I want to make two custom NewForms. Both will only have one editable field and both will have one hidden predefined field.

NewForm number 1 will have the Name column visible and Type selected as Male and hidden.

NewForm number 2 will have the Name column visible and Type selected as Female and hidden.

Is this possible?

Regards,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I implemented this :)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('select[title=ColumnName]').val('ValueYouWant');
$("nobr:contains('ColumnName')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is possible to modify the forms while the user is using them:
You can put the page into edit mode and add a Content Editor Web Part and fill it with javascript to do what you want. Or you can do the same using SharePoint Designer.

As for having more than one NewForm for a single list I don't know.

Comment: I also suspect it would be JavaScript I would have to use. Do you have any examples of this that I could use? I have a few examples how to hide fields but not how to define the choice and then hide it.

Comment: You will need to get the 'select' element and loop through the 'option' elements (select.options) that belong to it. If the value (select.options[i].value) or text (select.options[i].text) of the option is equal to the string you are looking for then set the selected property to true (select.options[i].selected=true). Then hide it as per your chosen method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new custom NewForm.aspx page by right clicking on the existing page in SharePoint Designer and choosing "New from Existing Page."

[image: New from Existing Page]

As Dan mentioned, you can add JavaScript to your page to hide or default values. An option for you would be to use [SPUtility.js](http://sputility.codeplex.com/) (full disclosure.. a JavaScript library I maintain):

```
SPUtility.GetSPField('Gender').SetValue('Male').Hide();
```

Comment: Yup you should be able to put your JavaScript code in the header of NewForm.aspx. I would put your script tags right after `<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">`.

Comment: This is an ideal solution. I get [object Error] however when I load the page. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry I removed my comment as I was able to add a WebPart eventually. Comment was regarding something locked me from adding a WebPart in Designer or editing the page with the  ToolPaneView=2 trick... 
My problem now is [object Error]. Any ideas?

Comment: @Dan: Thanks. :)
@David: I would double check you are including prototype.js and sputility.js. Both of these need to be uploaded to SharePoint somewhere and then included. Have a look at http://sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation: you'll need to use `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames` or `Event.observe`.

Comment: @Kit: They are indeed included and configured as per that page. I am still getting the object Error. I have tried with both _SpbOdyOnLoad and Event.observe.
Any way to trace the error?

Comment: I am slowly getting there... Now I am getting an error in the Dev tool
Error: Unable to get value of the property 'MakeReadOnly': object is null or undefined trying with:
<script type="text/javascript">

function ScheduledRepair() {

   SPUtility.GetSPField('Issue').MakeReadOnly();

}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ScheduledRepair");
</script>

Comment: @David, what type of field is `Issue`?

Comment: Hm.. it might be worthwhile to post all of the code in http://sputility.codeplex.com/discussions. What version of SharePoint? Is it a custom list with metadata?

Answer (score 0):

Call the below function and specify Field Name:

```
function HideField(FieldName)
{
$('nobr:contains("'+FieldName+'")').closest('tr').hide();
$('td.ms-formlabel:contains("'+FieldName+'")').parent().hide();
}
```